Conductive Materials
When one measures the resistance of a highly conductive material, like graphite (I am not sure how conductive it is actually - in comparison to other conductive materials); would it matter what is the initial resistance value of it before it is influenced by factors like temperature, pressure, etc?
Lets say I have a 0.6cm by 1cm sheet of graphite on a carbon coated aluminum foil, and I connect it to a multimeter, it gives me a value of around 110 Ohms but once I add a small pressure to it (say 25 Pa), it gives me a value of 109 Ohms. Would it matter if the starting and final resistance value for that area of graphite sheet matter? Or just the change in resistance values to know how conductive of a sample I have?

Aren't there references with material characteristics in them, like conductance, density etc

what do you mean? The graphite sheet is made from scratch by powder

Off hand, I'd say it is impossible to tell anything without reference to the initial values.  In all cases, you would be interested in the change relative to the initial value.  Is that what you were asking?
I'm not sure what the alternative would be. It is possible to pull a number out of a book, go out and obtain a 99.999+% pure sample of EXACTLY a calculated size and connect your meter leads with zero resistance and... MAYBE you'll get what you expect.  You can then perform tests of changes due to pressure, temperature, etc. but it would be much more productive to perform your tests relative to the initial values.
Don't forget to control your samples for the many variables.  That is make sure you are not changing the temperature of your sample when you apply pressure. It is much easier to keep the temperature constant than to try to back out the temperature effects afterwards.
My long winded story, sorry if this seems like a digression,

I was testing my welder by applying different currents through a
length of copper wire.  What I had not counted on was the welder is
constant current, if resistance increases, the voltage is  increased
to keep the current the same.  Minor annoyance, as the current heated
the wire, the resistance went up.  That meant the voltage went up
which meant the resistance went up (and you see where this is going).
I could not measure much of anything until I figured out to keep the
wire under water to keep the temperature (vaguely) constant.

If you want to measure anything useful, you have to control your environment.
